# MIME::Base64::decode_base64 wrong characters

Tags: perl, encoding, base64

I get some troubles using perl MIME::Base64::decode_base64

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use MIME::Base64;
$string_to_decrypt="lVvfrx23jX7vX3HghyJGxo4oivqBIg";
$content=MIME::Base64::decode_base64($string_to_decrypt);
open(WRITE,">/home/laurent/decrypted.txt");
print WRITE $content;
close(WRITE);
exit;
```

Using online decoder (like https://www.base64decode.org/) result should be:

```
[ß¯·~ï_qà"FÆ(ú"
```

But in my file, I get:

```
<95>[ß¯^]·<8d>~ï_qà<87>"FÆ<8e>(<8a>ú<81>"
```

I don't know how to get rid of:

```
 <95>, ^], <8d>,<87> ....
```

Thanks
Laurent

Comment: Tip: base64 is an encoding algorithm. It's not an encryption algorithm because there is no secret (key). As such, saying that `decode_base64` decrypts is inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly not text, so it's no surprise it doesn't render properly when printed as text. base64decode.org actually produces the same correct result as `decode_base64`, which is the following bytes:

```
95.5B.DF.AF.1D.B7.8D.7E.EF.5F.71.E0.87.22.46.C6.8E.28.8A.FA.81.22
```

You can use either of the following to remove the characters you identified, but that's is most definitely the wrong thing to do.

```
$content =~ tr/\x1D\x87\x8D\x95//d;
  -or-
$content =~ s/[\x1D\x87\x8D\x95]//g;
```